# Multiple languages in EditText without special characters

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, special-characters

I have an EditText, where I don't want to allow any special characters since I am storing this String in the SQLlite database. Right now I use:

```
<item name="android:digits">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</item>
```

This works fine for English. But when I switch my keyboard to a different language (Japanese, Russian, Hindi, etc), I am unable to enter anything. What is the right way to do this?

**Alternatively:**

I am using a ContentProvider to access my SQLite database. So I have methods reading/writing from and to database use

```
context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, values);
context.getContentResolver().query(uri, values); //for a special case, but only uses id=? in the query
context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values);
```

So do I need to escape the special characters at all?

Comment: What has storing the string in the database have to do with special characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
//try to add this fillter
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];

filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (end > start) {
            String destTxt = dest.toString();
            String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);

            if (!resultingTxt.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9?]*")) {
                if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString("");
                    return sp;
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
};

edtiText.setFilters(filters);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work with other languages either.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a little late to answer to your question but maybe this helps somebody in a future.

What you need is a filter like  Haresh's answer but modifing the regular expresion like:

```
    private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if(src.toString().matches("[\\p{Alnum}]*")){
            return src;
        }
        return "";
    }
};
```

If you don't want numbers in the editText then change

```
"[\\p{Alnum}]*"
```

with this

```
"[\\p{Alpha}]*"
```

If you need something more specific take a look to this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html):

PD: I used this code in my application that supports english, spanish and french language and it's working OK.

I hope this can help somebody!

Answer (score 0):

```
 binding.nafathUserNameEt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
        binding.nafathUserNameEt.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(
            InputFilter { src, start, end, dst, dstart, dend ->
                if (src == "") { return@InputFilter src }
                if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9,أآابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی,_-]+".toRegex())) { src } else ""
            }
        )
```